# Run code on coroutine close()

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine

I am writing code that uses coroutines heavily, and I want reliable behavior on shutdown.

Say I have a coroutine and a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def print_context_manager(text):
    print("Enter", text)
    yield
    print("Exit", text)

def coro():
    with print_context_manager("coro"):
        while True:
            print("Loop", (yield))
```

I could use it like this:

```
c = coro()
next(c)
c.send("Hello ")
c.send("World!")
c.close()
```

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there is no way to execute my own code on `c.close()`. In particular the context manager in coroutine never prints "Exit coro"

What's the point of context managers in coroutines? Do I have to manually come up with a way to signal the end of a stream? What's the point of `close()` then?

See this example: https://repl.it/M0XI/0

Comment: "In particular the file context manager in write_to_file coroutine never closes the file." Are you sure about this? I'd be surprised if closing coroutines didn't run finally blocks and exit out of context managers.

Comment: Whether for generator-coroutines or the new similar-but-different async coroutines, closing the coroutine runs `finally` blocks and `__exit__` methods. You don't need to write your own handling to do that.

Comment: Here is the example demonstrating the issue: https://repl.it/M0XI/0 . If you can see what I'm doing wrong, please let me know

Comment: That's because your context manager is written wrong. If the code in the `with` raises an exception, `@contextlib.contextmanager` raises that exception at the point of the `yield`, and your context manager doesn't deal with that. You need to wrap the `yield` in a try-finally and do cleanup in the `finally` if you want the cleanup to run even on an exception.

Comment: [Like this.](https://repl.it/M0XI/1)

Comment: Awesome! - let me redo my question to include my wrong code, and you can answer it the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context manager has a bug. Correct it, and it will automatically perform cleanup when the coroutine is closed.

Closing a coroutine works by raising `GeneratorExit` at the point where the coroutine is suspended. If the code in the `with` raises an exception, `@contextlib.contextmanager` raises that exception at the point of the `yield`. Your context manager doesn't deal with that, so the exception prevents the cleanup from running.

You need to wrap the `yield` in a try-finally and do cleanup in the `finally` if you want the cleanup to run even on an exception:

```
@contextmanager
def print_context_manager(text):
    print("Enter", text)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print("Exit", text)
```