# Sequential version of asyncio.gather

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I tried to create a method similar to asyncio.gather, but which will execute the list of tasks sequentially and not asynchronously:

```
async def in_sequence(*tasks):
    """Executes tasks in sequence"""
    for task in tasks:
        await task
```

Next this method was supposed to be used like this:

```
async def some_work(work_name):
    """Do some work"""
    print(f"Start {work_name}")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if raise_exception:
        raise RuntimeError(f"{work_name} raise an exception")
    print(f"Finish {work_name}")

async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(
            some_work("work1"),         # work1, work2, in_sequence and work5 executed in concurrently
            some_work("work2"),
            in_sequence(
                some_work("work3"),     # work3 and work4 executed in sequence
                some_work("work4")
            ),
            some_work("work5"),


    except RuntimeError as error:
        print(error)                    # raise an exception at any point to terminate
```

And everything worked fine until I tried to throw an exception in some_work:

```
async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(
            some_work("work1"),
            some_work("work2"),
            in_sequence(
                some_work("work3", raise_exception=True),       # raise an exception here
                some_work("work4")
            ),
            some_work("work5"),


    except RuntimeError as error:
        print(error)
```

Immediately after that, I received the following error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'some_work' was never awaited
```

I read the documentation and continued to experiment:

```
async def in_sequence(*tasks):
    """Executes tasks in sequence"""
    _tasks = []
    for task in tasks:
        _tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(task))

    for _task in _tasks:
        await _task
```

And this version worked as expected!

In this regard, I have next questions:

1. Why does the second version work and the first not?
2. Does asyncio already have the tools to execute the list of tasks
   sequentially?
3. Have I chosen the right implementation method or are there better
   options?

Answer (score 2):

You said that version of in_sequence works(with asyncio.create_task), but I think it does not. From docs

> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return
>   the Task object.

It seems that it runs coroutines in parallel, but you need them in sequence.

So experimented and found two ways how to fix this

Use your original in_sequence function and add this code, that hides that error:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(
    'ignore',
    message=r'^coroutine .* was never awaited$',
    category=RuntimeWarning
)
```

Fix in_sequence function, like this:

```
async def in_sequence(*tasks):
    for index, task in enumerate(tasks):
        try:
            await task
        except Exception as e:
            for task in tasks[index + 1:]:
                task.close()
            raise e
```

Answers on other questions:

1. That warnings is triggered by C++ code, when you do not have links on coroutine. just simple code can show you this idea(in terminal):

---

```
async def test():
    return 1

f = test()
f = None # after that you will get that error
```

2. I do not know
3. See above

Comment: "Fix in_sequence function, likes this". It seems this code counts on Python implementation detail of generator-based coroutines.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it seems [it will be removed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#generator-based-coroutines) it Python 3.10

Comment: I do not think that I use generator base coroutines

Comment: I didn't find any public documentation about `close()` method of coroutines and generators have this method. As I said I don't know exactly, but it looks suspicious

Comment: You are right. I have misunderstood what generator-based coroutine is. It is just about `asycnio.coroutine` decorator. PS I have found [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects) about `close`

Comment: It seems that the method you proposed to catch the exception seems to be the most acceptable. But I can not find a description of the close() method (meaning task.close())

Comment: I found it using console with dir(couroutine). Some additional info you can find there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677432/run-code-on-coroutine-close

Answer (score 1):

1. The first version doesn't work because `in_sequence` doesn't catch an exception which can be raised on `await task`. The second works because `create_task` creates a future-like [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) object that runs coroutine. The object doesn't return/propagate a result of the wrapped coroutine. 
   When you `await` the object, it suspends until either has [a result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.set_result) or [an exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.set_exception) **set** or until [it is canceled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.cancel).
2. It seems it hasn't.
3. The second version will execute passed coroutines concurrently, so it is incorrect implementation. If you really want to use some `in_sequence` function you can:

   - Somehow delay the creation of coroutines.
   - Group sequential execution in an `async` function

e.g.:

```py
async def in_sequence(*fn_and_args):
    for fn, args, kwargs in fn_and_args:
        await fn(*args, **kwargs)  # create a coro and await it in place

in_sequence(
    (some_work, ("work3",), {'raise_exception': True}),
    (some_work, ("work4",), {}),
)
```

```py
async def in_sequence():
    await some_work("work3", raise_exception=True)
    await some_work("work4")
```

Answer (score 1):

> And this version worked as expected!

The problem with the second version is that it doesn't actually run the coroutines sequentially, it runs them in parallel. This is because `asyncio.create_task()` schedules the coroutine to run in parallel with the current coroutines. So when you await tasks in a loop, you are actually allowing all the tasks to run while awaiting the first one. Despite appearances, the whole loop will run for only as long as the longest task. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674375/1600898) for more details.)

The warning displayed by your first version is intended to prevent you from accidentally creating a coroutine that you never await, e.g. writing just `asyncio.sleep(1)` instead of `await asyncio.sleep(1)`. As far as asyncio is concerned, `main` is instantiating coroutine objects and passing them to `in_sequence` which "forgets" to await some of them.

One way to suppress the warning message is to allow the coroutine to spin, but cancel it immediately.  For example:

```
async def in_sequence(*coros):
    remaining = iter(coros)
    for coro in remaining:
        try:
            await coro
        except Exception:
            for c in remaining:
                asyncio.create_task(c).cancel()
            raise
```

Note that a variable name that begins with an underscore marks an unused variable, so you shouldn't name variables so if you actually do use them.

Comment: I believe Task.cancel() internally uses Coroutine.close()

Comment: @Cynic Quite possible. It's normally also injects the appropriate exception into the coroutine, which of course does nothing for a coroutine that never started executing. The point of this response is that it only uses the high-level API, leaving it to asyncio to properly dispose of the coroutine object you no longer need.

Comment: One question tormenting me - Why, instead of catching the exception and then throwing it again, just don't use the finally block? I mean, place the 'try' before 'for'.

Comment: @Cynic That would be a valid implementation, yes. It didn't occur to me because I wanted to explicitly handle the exception raised from `await`, whereas `finally` runs regardless of whether an exception actually occurred. But with the `try` placed outside the loop, `finally` would work as well, because if there was no exception, `remaining` would just be empty.

Comment: I think the following question may seem interesting to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070740/how-to-properly-terminate-nested-asyncio-tasks

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from user4815162342's and Anton Pomieshchenko's solutions, I came up with this variation of it:

```py
async def in_sequence(*storm):
    twister = iter(storm)
    for task in twister:
        task = task() # if it's a regular function, it's done here.
        if inspect.isawaitable(task):
            try:
                await task # if it's also awaitable, await it
            except BaseException as e:
                task.throw(e) # if an error occurs, throw it into the coroutine
            finally:
                task.close() # to ensure coroutine closer

    assert not any(twister) # optionally verify that the iterator is now empty
```

this way you can combine regular functions with coroutines with this `in_sequence`. But make sure to call it like this:

```py
await in_sequence(*[b.despawn, b.release])
```

Notice the lack of `()` (`__call__()`), because otherwise the regular function would be called immediately and the coroutine would throw a `RuntimeWarning` for having never been awaited. ( `b.despawn` is a coroutine and `b.release` is not for my example)

You can also do an additional check for `callable(task)` just before invoking `task()`, but it's up to you.

Comment: Why are you throwing the exception the task gave you back into it? The only exceptions from `await task` (after you've already checked `inspect.isawaitable`) should be things that task itself threw (and thus already handled as much as it was going to), or things from the bowels of the Python runtime that no Python code is generally written to handle (like "out of memory"), right? Or are there other exceptions that I'm not thinking of?