# How to properly terminate nested asyncio-tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026643/sequential-version-of-asyncio-gather) asked how I can make a version of asyncio.gather that executes the list of tasks sequentially and not in parallel, and good people told me how. But my joy ended as soon as I tried to put two in_sequence() methods into one another:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Coroutine


async def work_a():
    print("Work 'A' start")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print("Work 'A' finish")


async def work_b():
    print("Work 'B' start")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print("Work 'B' finish")


async def raise_exception():
    print("raise_exception executed")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    raise RuntimeError("raise_exception executed")


async def in_sequence(*tasks: Coroutine):
    """Executes coroutines in sequence"""
    tasks = iter(tasks)
    try:
        for task in tasks:
            await task

    # Terminates all other tasks scheduled for execution in event loop to prevent "RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited" message
    finally:
        for remaining_task in tasks:
            remaining_task.close()

async def main():
    try:
        await in_sequence(              # outer in_sequence()
            work_a(),
            raise_exception(),
            in_sequence(                # inner in_sequence()
                work_b()
            )
        )

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"+++ Quit with exception: {e}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

As a result, I received the following output with "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'work_b' was never awaited" error:

```
Work 'A' start
Work 'A' finish
raise_exception executed
+++ Quit with exception: raise_exception executed
{some path}\terminate_inner_coroutine_issue.py:33: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'work_b' was never awaited
  remaining_task.close()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

After several experiments, I realized what the problem was: When the raise_exception() method throws an exception in the outer in_sequence() method, the outer in_sequence() method terminates only its child tasks in the finally block, i.e. only inner in_sequence(). In turn, the inner in_sequence() does not terminate its nested task work_b(), because at the moment when an exception occurs, inner in_sequence() is not yet running and the error occurs.

In further experiments, I “invented” the following version of in_sequence() which seems to solve the problem:

```
async def in_sequence(name: str, *tasks: Coroutine):
    """Executes coroutines in sequence"""
    print(f"in_sequence '{name}' start")
    tasks = iter(tasks)
    try:
        for task in tasks:
            await task

    except asyncio.CancelledError as c:
        print(f"+++ in_sequence '{name}' catch CancelledError: {c}")

    finally:
        # Terminates all other tasks scheduled for execution in event loop
        for remaining_task in tasks:
            print(f"+++ Cancel {remaining_task}")
            remaining_task.send(None)
            try:
                # Will be raised asyncio.CancelledError in coroutine
                remaining_task.throw(asyncio.CancelledError)

            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass
            # remaining_task.close()                                                      # >>> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'work_b' was never awaited
            # asyncio.create_task(remaining_task).cancel()                                # >>> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'work_b' was never awaited
            # asyncio.create_task(remaining_task).set_exception(asyncio.CancelledError)   # >>> Exception - Task does not support set_exception operation

    print(f"in_sequence '{name}' finish")
```

and returns the following output:

```
in_sequence '1' start
Work 'A' start
Work 'A' finish
raise_exception executed
+++ Cancel <coroutine object in_sequence at 0x0000024AF58B6AC0>
in_sequence '2' start
Work 'B' start
+++ in_sequence '2' catch CancelledError: 
in_sequence '2' finish
+++ Quit with exception: coroutine raised StopIteration
```

The questions:

1. Is this the correct solution or are there better options? How to
   terminate child tasks in such a situation?
2. Is it normal that a 'coroutine raised StopIteration' exception
   throws in my implementation?

Comment: I would steer away from such a complex solution, it seems way too likely to attract bugs. At this point I would throw in the towel and choose the delayed coroutine creation route, as kindly shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027869/1600898). It eliminates all your issues and happens to be the approach taken by both [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#trio.Nursery.start) and [curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#spawn).

Answer (score 0):

The cancelling try-catch pattern is clunky. Firstly, we want to know about the RuntimeException but instead we're looking at the CancelledError, which is annoying.  Secondly, think **Futures** think **promises** - don't go round creating Futures you might not follow up on. You wouldn't break a promise, why a Future?

If we know there is a chance we might change out mind, instead of passing around built and ready (even expecting to be) run Futures, pass around coro signatures that can be build JIT (Just In Time) instead. I have the full code below for you, but the take home is that you should pass round the type `Callable[[], Coroutine]` instead of just `Coroutine`, then build the coro just as you need it.

```
import asyncio
from typing import Coroutine, Callable


async def work_a():
    print("Work 'A' start")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print("Work 'A' finish")


async def work_b():
    print("Work 'B' start")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print("Work 'B' finish")


async def raise_exception():
    print("raise_exception executed")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    raise RuntimeError("raise_exception executed")


def in_sequence(*arg_tasks: Callable[[], Coroutine]) -> Callable[[], Coroutine]: # <-- New signature
    async def coro():
        """Executes coroutines in sequence"""
        tasks = iter(arg_tasks)
        try:
            for task in tasks:
                await task()   # <-- create JIT

        # Terminates all other tasks scheduled for execution in event loop to prevent "RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited" message
        finally:
            for remaining_task in tasks:
                pass
                # remaining_task.close() # <-- Not needed now
    return coro


async def main():
    try:
        await in_sequence(              # outer in_sequence()
            work_a,
            raise_exception,
            in_sequence(                # inner in_sequence()
                work_b
            )
        )()     #<-- Remember to call to build coro

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"+++ Quit with exception: {e}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Outputs:

```
Work 'A' start
Work 'A' finish
raise_exception executed
+++ Quit with exception: raise_exception executed

Process finished with exit code 0
```